# CoreData Mapping Model syntax to change a relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, migration

DBv1

Widget has many-to-one relationship to Model1. i.e. Widget.model1, Model1.widgets.

DBv2

Widgets need to be moved so that they have a many-to-one relationship to Model2. Model2 has a one-to-many relationship with Model1 (in both versions of the DB). i.e. Widget.model2, Model2.widgets, Model2.model1s, Model1.model2

I am trying to set Widget's model2 relationship with something like:

```
FUNCTION($manager, "destinationInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:sourceInstances:" , "Model2ToModel2", $source.model1.model2)
```

The logic being that the original record $source has a model1 relationship, which in turn has a model2 relationship, so I'm trying to grab the model2 via the original model1.

All the relationships end up as NULL. Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: To make the relationships (hopefully) clearer:

DBv1

Model2
 - has many Model1s

Model1
 - has many Widgets

DBv2

Model2
 - has many Model1s
 - has many Widgets

i.e. I want to move the Widget relationship up one level from Model1 to Model2.

Answer (score 0):

The model2 relationship on Widget was specified as optional. This evidently means that the migration won't be run for that property. You don't appear to get any feedback either.

So this works as expected. Set up the new properties in the model correctly and set the migration mapping as indicated above.